# Set default value for a segment

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-mapper

I have for example 3 lines for DTM (EDIFACT schema) segment:

```
DTM+2:20200619:102'
DTM+137:20200617:102'
DTM+11:20200619:102
```

If the first value is not 361 I have to set a default value but in the output should to appear one time not three times (for each line).

Comment: So you are mapping to the EDIFACT schema?   Can you give a sample input and expected output and an example of how you are mapping currently and the current output, highlighting where it is wrong